# Regarding "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, security

First post here. I'd gotten into python a couple months prior. I've been working through the book 'Violent Python' by Syngress.

Made a txt file listing several versions of vsFTPd, saved as vuln_banners.txt. It's just a list of about a handful of lines in a txt file.

What am I doing wrong? I apologize if this is a stupid question or extremely rudimentary/silly. Appreciate the help in any form.

After running the code I have gotten this traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ban_grab2.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "ban_grab2.py", line 29, in main
    checkVulns(banner)
  File "ban_grab2.py", line 18, in checkVulns
    if line.strip('\n') in banner:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Below is the section of code in question:

```
def checkVulns(banner):
    f = open('vuln_banners.txt', 'r')
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.strip('\n') in banner:
            print('[+] Service is vulnerable: ' + banner.strip('\n'))
```

Here's the full script if this helps give better context to the situation:

```
import socket


def retBanner(ip, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((ip, port))
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
        banner = s.recv(1024)
        return banner
    except:
        return


def checkVulns(banner):
    f = open('vuln_banners.txt', 'r')
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.strip('\n') in banner:
            print('[+] Service is vulnerable: ', + banner.strip('\n')


def main():
    portList = [21, 22, 25, 80, 110, 443]
    for r in range(1, 255):
        ip = '192.168.0.' + str(r)
        for port in portList:
            banner = retBanner(ip, port)
            if banner:
                checkVulns(banner)
                print('[+] ' + ip + ': ' + str(banner))


main()
```

This script isn't anything amazing, just using this within my virtual network for POC.

Answer (score 3):

I believe, somehow you're passing `bytes` object as `banner` argument to your function.

And issue is `banner.strip('\n')` – either you should have string and strip string off it, or strip bytes with `banner.strip(b'\n')` (but you'll have issues with concatenation later).

Mixing strings and raw bytes is generally a bad idea, until you know what you're doing. I suggest you tracing where and how your function being called

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll take what you said and try to work through this and figure it out.

Comment: I edited the original post to show the full gamut of what's going on. Still getting the same error as shown above. I'm not sure what it is I'm doing wrong. I tried adding 'b' in with `banner.strip(b'\n')` to strip bytes and that didn't seem to work.

What's meant by 'you should have string and strip string off it'? 

Thanks for any help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `in` but, you are not iterating, so:

```
if line.strip("\n") == banner:
```

Comment: * iterating, sorry, I'm improving my English

Comment: You can (and should) [edit] your answer if you need to fix something.